# Remote Logging with syslog

Tags: freebsd, syslog, remote-access, syslogd

I have two machines running FreeBSD, bsdclient and bsdserver. I am trying to setup remote logging such that bsdclient sends all the logs to bsdserver. My syslog.conf on bsdclient goes like this

```
*.*        @bsdserver.domain.com
```

On bsdserver, the syslog.conf is configured as:

```
+bsdclient.domain.com
*.*        /var/log/bsdclient.log
```

syslogd in bsdserver was started in rc.conf as:

```
syslogd_enable="YES"
syslogd_flags="-a bsdclient.domain.com"
```

To test, on bsdclient i did

```
logger -p auth.info "user authenticated"
```

I can see entry in the /var/log/auth.log on bsdclient, however there is nothing in the /var/log/bsdclient.log on bsdserver. I am trying to send all type of logs to bsdserver. Did i make any mistake?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is bsdclient.domain.com and bsdserver.domain.com global DNS aware ? If not have you tried putting in an IP instead of DNS names.

Please following this excellent handbook section from [freebsd handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-syslogd.html)

Comment: the machines are not connected to any other network, it's just a network between two machines and the domains are well configured. There is no problem accessing two machines with their domain. However, i've even tried with their IPs, no luck.. Could you suggest any way I can debug the whole thing??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, turn on verbosity on the server:

```
syslogd_flags="-a bsdclient.domain.com -v -v"
```

And on the client:

```
syslog_flags="-s -v -v"
```

That'll give you more information.

Have you configured a logging facility on the client yet, to tell syslog what to log?
To find out more about it look at the aforementioned Handbook and [the syslog Manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syslog.conf&sektion=5)

Comment: thanks for the reply, it still does not solve the main problem..

Comment: Well, with the added verbosity you should get some more information on what is going on, though. Because right now, you kind of give no information at all, which doesn't make debugging this any easier.